# About anchor element in HTML

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

[image]

```
<h1>My top 5 Favorite Websites</h1>

<ol>
    <li>
        <a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">Youtube</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="https://www.udemy.com/">Udemy</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="https://www.wikipedia.com/">Wikipedia</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

This is my code. When I click in the website from index.html to any of the links, all it does is open the browser (Google Chrome) and show me a page similar to the preview of my code. i.e. the preview in VS code and clicking the link for the website both show the same result.

How do I correct it?

I was expecting it to directly run the Google page when I click on Google on the preview of VSCode. After I click on any of the titles it takes me to Chrome like in the picture instead of running the website.